# How To Use Apple's Notification Sounds for User Notifications Swift

Tags: swift, notifications, system-sounds, unusernotification

I am wondering if it is possible to have one of Apple's notification sounds on a user notification instead of always using `UNNotificationSound.default()` for sounds or have the user be able to go into settings a pick a sound of choice.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use any system sounds. The available system sounds are located in `Library/Audio`, but you can only use sounds from `Library/Sounds`.

However, you can still provide custom sounds the user can choose from through supplying the sound files and initializing using `init(named:)`.